# .Net Core CSharp Custom Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, .net

How can i perform custom deserialization of this object in .Net Core C#, that Afpak is assigned as 'string name' in this object class. I have the following JSon Code of the object:

```
{
"Afpak": {
    "id": 1,
    "race": "hybrid",
    "flavors": [
        "Earthy",
        "Chemical",
        "Pine"
    ],
    "effects": {
        "positive": [
            "Relaxed",
            "Hungry",
            "Happy",
            "Sleepy"
        ],
        "negative": [
            "Dizzy"
        ],
        "medical": [
            "Depression",
            "Insomnia",
            "Pain",
            "Stress",
            "Lack of Appetite"
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note the object class is Strain, it gets variable name from root of this json - in this case the name variable would be Afpak, there is 100s of different Strain class objects in this one JSON code is what I am having trouble with as it doesnt make sense to create each one as seperate class if it is all of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

you should implement a class exposing the properties you want to map from that JSON object.
Something like this:

```
public class AfpakDto{
   public string id {get;set;}
   public string race {get;set;}
   public string[] flavors {get;set;}
}
public class FooDto {
   public AfpakDto Afpak {get; set;}
}
```

and then use whatever library you want. Here's a nice article about System.Text.JSON: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: Issue is that all of this objects is one class, meaning the root of object is the name of variable in this class, is there a way to go around it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly what you mean. Your JSON object has an "Afpak" property, which is a complex object, not a primitive (eg. string, number etc). You have to define a class mapping it, and do the same for each "complex object" you have in the hierarchy.